# Eager loading taking more time to load page in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to play around with Eager Loading in a nonperformant app that has a n+1 of 5000 objects. This is the query with eager loading:

```
 2855, 2856, 2857, 2858, 2859, 2860, 2861, 2862, 2863, 2864, 2865, 2866, 2867, 2868, 2869, 2870, 2871, 2872, 2873, 2874, 2875, 2876, 2877, 2878, 2879, 2880, 2881, 2882, 2883, 2884, 2885, 2886, 2887, 2888, 2889, 2890, 2891, 2892, 2893, 2894, 2895, 2896, 2897, 2898, 2899, 2900, 2901, 2902, 2903, 2904, 2905, 2906, 2907, 2908, 2909, 2910, 2911, 2912, 2913, 2914, 2915, 2916, 2917, 2918, 2919, 2920, 2921, 2922, 2923, 2924, 2925, 2926, 2927, 2928, 2929, 2930, 2931, 2932, 2933, 2934, 2935, 2936, 2937, 2938, 2939, 2940, 2941, 2942, 2943, 2944, 2945, 2946, 2947, 2948, 2949, 2950, 2951, 2952, 2953, 2954, 2955, 2956, 2957, 2958, 2959, 2960, 2961, 2962, 2963, 2964, 2965, 2966, 2967, 2968, 2969, 2970, 2971, 2972, 2973, 2974, 2975, 2976, 2977, 2978, 2979, 2980, 2981, 2982, 2983, 2984, 2985, 2986, 2987, 2988, 2989, 2990, 2991, 2992, 2993, 2994, 2995, 2996, 2997, 2998, 2999, 3000, 3001)
  Rendered author/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2373.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2398ms (Views: 2357.5ms | ActiveRecord: 40.3ms)
```

It's way faster in view load time and AR load time than lazy loading (if I used .all, it took like 10 seconds to load), but for some reason the page is hanging for longer than 10 seconds now even though the view is taking longer to load. Any idea why?

Comment: Maybe because you're loading 5000 objects? Have you heard about pagination?

Comment: I have, but I'm wondering why loading 5000 objects is slower in eager loading than lazy loading? Isn't this a problem common to both eager loading and lazy loading? Why is the page taking longer to load using eager loading now than lazy loading?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're talking about eager loading, it means there's a sql `JOIN` happening under the hood, and if, for example, each author has many posts, that means that 1 query will have to load 5000 authors with all their posts, which is a very big number, in opposite to lazy loading, where you have LOTS of queries, but they're quite easy and fast (if you have indexes on right columns), but since there's a lot of them, it's still slow.

Nevertheless, it's not performance wise to load 5000 objects at once, this makes a very heavy load on your database, and none of your users doesn't need all that data at once. Imagine, what if Google would give you 5000 pages on your search query - that would just stopped the search, since a) it would create a heavy load on Google servers, and b) the page would be very heavy to load it fast that would cause a lot of frustration to users.

Consider integrating some pagination gems, such as [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) or [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate).

UPDATE: There's a [wonderful article](http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/) about different types of eager loading in Rails (yeah, there are many of them), it's a very interesting reading.

Have fun!

Comment: but my activerecord time when down from 4 seconds to 4 miliseconds. Aren't I saving time with eager loading?

Comment: I can't say anything for sure, until you show me the code, because I don't know neither your database structure, nor the code you're running. If eager loading worked for you - great, but you should understand _why_ is it working, because otherwise when it breaks, you won't be able to fix it back. Have a look at your development.log and try to see some patterns. You'll need to have some SQL knowledge for that.

Comment: My guess is that loading 5000 objects at once vs 10 objects at once isn't merely 50x longer. The relationship doesn't seem linear. Right now, my AR time in my post above is 40ms... which is much shorter than lazily loading objects with an N+1 problem. That's what I'm confused about since my page for some reason is taking longer to load now with eager loading.

Comment: I can only guess what's going on in your app, since I can't see your code. Maybe it's rendering now is taking so long, who knows? Install https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler and see where's the bottleneck